# Mass in Wilsonian RG (vs. mass in ordinary RG)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mass, renormalization, regularization

The essence of Wilson RG can be described in tree steps:

Initially we have some theory on scale $\Lambda$.

1. Lower cut-off $\Lambda^\prime =\zeta^{-1}\Lambda<\Lambda$ and integrate out d.o.f. with $\Lambda^\prime<k<\Lambda$
2. Place initial and final theory on a level by rescaling momenta and coordinate:

$$
k^\prime = \zeta k
$$
$$
x^\prime = \zeta^{-1}x
$$

3. Rescale the fields so that gradient term remains canonically normalised

As the result of such procedure, **mass term will scale even in free theory**:

$$
\boxed{m^2(\zeta) = \zeta^2 m_0^2}
$$

**What does it really mean? Does it mean that particle mass change?**

How to relate this result to standard approach: [What is the difference between pole and running mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31261/)

It is quite hard to me realise relation to ordinary QFT framework. **In ordinary approach in free theory we haven't any corrections and so we haven't flow of mass parameter**.

Comment: For interacting theories, it is not true that $m^2(\zeta) = \zeta^2 m_0^2$, since the flow of the mass can be non-trivial (close to a non-trivial fixed point for example).

Comment: @Adam,  you are right. I just wanna to understant simplest example.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of Wilsonian RG in terms of coarse graining in real/coordinate space. Say we are on a square lattice, and there is a “structure” on the lattice of linear dimensions $L_0 = m_0^{-1}$, which can be written in units of the lattice spacing ($a$) as $L_0 = a \tilde{m}^{-1}$. The lowering of the cutoff in momentum space is equivalent to probing the real space lattice at a larger scale, i.e. increasing the lattice spacing $a \to a’= \xi a$. Now in terms of the new lattice spacing $L_0 = a’ (\tilde{m}’)^{-1}$. Thus the measured value of the linear dimension of the “structure” has changed to $\tilde m’ =  \xi \tilde{m}$. This is the essence of the mass rescaling as the system is probed at different length/momentum/energy scales. It does not require interactions.

The key to relate it to field theoretic renormalization is to think in terms of a Callan-Symanzik equations for the non-interacting field theory.

Comment: Thank you! But you didn't answer my question. In ordinary RG for free theory, mass doesn't run. But in Wilsonian RG mass is running. Also, does it mean that particle mass really change?

Comment: Wilsonian RG has two parts, viz. (i) dimensionful quantities look different at different scales; (ii) dressings due to quantum fluctuations. The former is identical to classical/engineering scaling dimension in field theoretic RG. As an example, one can consider the beta functions of massive, scalar $\phi^4$ theory in spacetime $D<4$, and turn off the interaction.

Comment: do you agree, that mass in Wilsonian RG and in ordinary RG run differently?

Comment: If you are asking whether the beta function for mass in the two RG schemes are distinct, then the answer is in the negative. A dimensionful parameter always runs in the sense that it carries a finite engineering scaling dimension, and will "look" different at different energy scales. This is a statement that is applicable at tree-level itself.

Comment: Could you derive Wilson RG and ordinary RG for mass in free theory and compare results? I think, that I didn't explain my question enough..

Comment: Yes. Would be useful to compare the mode-elimination RG as discussed by R. Shankar (doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.66.129), with dimensional regularization based discussions of $\phi^4$ theory in $D<4$.